# Write a text file with a defined maximum lines count in java

Tags: java, text

Hi all
Is it possible to write a .txt file in java with a certain number of lines?

Pratically I have to write a file in append mode, for example with a maximum of 4 lines:

```
File .txt 1

item1
item2
item3
item4
```

When the files reaches 4 lines, writing on it can't be allowed and a new file is generated

```
File .txt 2

item5
item6
....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a library API for this, but it wouldn't be too hard to write your own.  Upon opening the file for writing, you could read the number of lines and then count them as they are written, rolling over as necessary

YOu could use RandomAccessFile to do both reading and writing in one pass http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html

Answer (score 2):

Most logging frameworks do this.  Why reinvent the wheel?  Look into [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/).